# reRender a JSF1.2 componente programmatically

Tags: jsf, richfaces, rerender

Sometimes, I have to reRender some component in my applications (using JSF1.2 and RichFaces 3.3.2).

Is possible to do that programmatically in server side, or just the old school way, in client side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components are always rendered on the server (markup is then sent to the browser for DOM update). If you need to decide in runtime which components to re-render, you can do reRender=#{bean.compoentsToRender}

Comment: yep, I knew that. But I want to decide in server when do the reRender.

Comment: Decide when or what components?

Comment: when and what, if i just could call a JS in server side, i Would be happy :)

Comment: what is defined with reRender or a4j:outputPanel. As to when, has to come from a user action or a4j:poll or a4j:push

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`<a4j:poll>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_poll.html) or [`<a4j:push>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_push.html).